# getDay() JavaScript return 0 while trying to fetch date from my full date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to put on screen the current date whit this code

```
function getDate() {
    var when = new Date();
    var year = when.getFullYear(), month = when.getMonth(), day = when.getDay() ;
    var date='<div>'+ year + " " + (month+1) + " " + day +'</div>';
    console.log(day);       //console said 0
    return date;
}
```

Today (2020, March, 22) date has been shown like this in HTML
2020 3 0
I tryied also switching to another browser.
Thank you

Comment: `getDay` is day of week (0 = sunday). You want `getDate`

Comment: I don't understand why question is down-voted. this is genuine scenario I encountered today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The `getDay()` method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

---

What you want is `getDate()`:

> The `getDate()` method returns the day of the month for the specified date according to local time. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate).

---

Here is a live example:

```js
var when = new Date();
var year = when.getFullYear(), month = when.getMonth(), day = when.getDate();

console.log(year, month, day);
```